# Encoding/patching variable in other .exe

Tags: c++, encoding, reverse-engineering, exe

I'm out of ideas how to do this :

You have one file, let's call it test.exe,

it has const int value = 5; in it, and all it does is cout << value;

I want to create other executable which patches the test.exe so it now outputs 10 instead of 5. I want this to be done before runtime.

I've tried turning off the ASLR, getting the address of that variable and then patching in, but addresses in disk and in memory differ AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this remark assumes you are working on a Windows System. If not, I'm sure that with other executable image formats you can follow similar method.

Assuming you are trying to ask how you alter data within a target and not how to, in this particular example, change the screens output...

Have you considered looking at the executable image's PE Header? You can translate the address of a particular piece of data once loaded into memory to its offset in the PE file but taking a look at the IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER structure inside of PE Header of the image in question.

First, calculate the RVA of your data in memory. This is the address of the data relative to the section it is located inside of.

Second, index through the IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER structures inside of the executable's PE header by reading the header from file into a buffer. Once you've loaded this header into a memory buffer, you can process it using pointers. Like so,

```
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pImageHeader = &peHeaderBuffer[0];
```

After finding the correct IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER that contains your data,you can access the PointerToRawData member of the structure which will give you the offset from the start of the PE file at which this section is, if you add the RVA, you will get the offset from the start of the file from which your data is located.

Obviously, my response doesn't explain how to index through the section headers as this is a fairly tedious task that would take a while to explain. I would suggest you take a look at an exectuable's PE header from within a simple debugger, like OllyDbg, and reference MSDN's documentations on the PE Header - which can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680336%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

If all you want to do is reverse this information our of a target, it is very easy to do using OllyDbg. Just skim down the PE Header view until you see the section that corresponds to your data, and OllyDbg will list the PointerToRawData member there, which you can add to your RVA.

Comment: "After finding the correct IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER that contains your data". So when I calculate the RVA how do I know that specific header contains my data?

Comment: I should have been more descriptive, sorry. 
the Data's Address in Memory is between IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER::VirtualAddress + [PE's Base address in memory] and IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER::VirtualAddress + [PE's Base address in memory] +  [Sections size, in memory]

Comment: I'm getting confused, so for example I know that in memory my data is always at 18FF3C, what is done next?

Comment: If you are trying to accomplish this quickly you should use Sergius's method, I must admit mine does have quite a learning curve to it and isn't necessary unless you are programatically translating the address to an offset. Seeing as you're doing it manually, it is probably easier to follow Sergius method.

With that said, find out which section, in memory, 18FF3C is located.If you're lucky it will have a name. From that, subtract the sections base from 18FF3C. So if the base address was 180000, then your RVA is 0xFF3C. If the size of that section is > your RVA, this section contains the data

Answer (score 1):

Find it by signature: get 8-16 bytes around your value 5 and then search for them in .exe binary.

Also note that usually const int values are inlined into the assembler code, so if you have 2 or more statements referencing to it you have to patch all of them.

Comment: If the numeric constant is only output to the screen, it may also be optimized into a string constant, which might be difficult to patch in the EXE because "10" takes one more byte of memory than "5". There may be no unused byte right after "5\0".

Comment: While using a signature is one way to do it, I don't think its appropriate when, at least on a windows machine, it  can be easily translated using structure in the PE Header - and I'm sure other executable image formats have a similar sort of feature.

Comment: @user1070878: Yes, you can calculate where your variable is using PE header, but searching by signature is easier. You can do it in a hex editor by hands (no calculations required) and use a patch generator to make an exe for automatic patching.

Comment: Agreed, however to programatically translate an address from its location on disk to its location once loaded into an address space and vise-versa using a signature is messy and unreliable - which is what I was trying to get across. There is nothing wrong with using your suggestion manually though.